# Bazaar: check out specific subfolders

Tags: bazaar

How can I check out only certain subfolders from a branch in Bazaar? 
Example:

Given the branch consisting of:

/myapp
/myapp/doc
/myapp/bin
/my
/myapp/bunch-o-crap

how do I create a versioned working copy of just

/myapp/doc
/myapp/bin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

Distributed version control software like git, mercurial and bzr do work on the complete repository as a single unit. This is required for storing the history of moved files etc properly.

Comment: Yes, but once I have cloned or branched the repo, it must be possible to selectively create my working copy..? Or do I really have to have every single file in the entire repo in my working copy?

Comment: Ah, using 'bzr view' lets me only see the files I want to work with.